# Configure Latex compiler to continue typesetting using a placeholder for undefined control sequences

Tags: undefined, draft

I am trying to write a paper while using yet-undefined macros all around.  I will define them, but sometime later.  I find it distracting to go back to preamble and define them, especially when I haven't even decided how to define them.

Meanwhile, I would like it better if my draft were to compile.  Is it possible to make `pdftex` or `latexmk` to fall back to placeholders for macros that aren't yet defined?

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

% This should compile as if the following line was uncommented
% \newcommand\test{\textbackslash test}

\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could use `\csname test\endcsname` in the document, then they would fallback to relax. But it is less trouble to get the habit to create a dummy definition when needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Exactly. I would much rather write the line I wrote in the example, if I was OK about the context switching involved in go and edit the preamble.

Comment: `\test` will always give an (low-level tex) error unless you define it, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: if you want to introduce errors then simply add `\batchmode` at the top of your document and tex will scroll past the errors.

Comment: why introduce an error syntax (which as Ulrike says is more or less impossible to trap) if you wrote  a different syntax such as `\Z test ` then you could define `\Z#1 {...}` to use `\test` if it is defined or do anything you want if it is not defined.